# EWS - Can't load FirstDayOfWeek property of Appointment.Recurrence

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I can successfully load the [Recurrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.recurrence(v=exchg.80).aspx) property for an [Appointment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment(v=exchg.80).aspx) using EWS (connecting to an Office 365 server), but when I try to access the [FirstDayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.firstdayofweek(v=exchg.80).aspx) property of a [WeeklyPattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern(v=exchg.80).aspx) I always get the following exception:

```
FirstDayOfWeek threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceValidationException
```

All other properties of the `WeeklyPattern` seem to load happily (see below) except this.

[image]

Is it possibly down to the [requested server version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb891876(v=exchg.150).aspx) I'm using when creating the [ExchangeService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice(v=exchg.80).aspx) object?

```
thisConnection = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
```

I've checked the `AppointmentSchema` properties available when loading the Appointment, and other than `AppointmentSchema.Recurrence` (which I am obviously using) there doesn't seem to be anything else I'm missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FirstDayOfWeek` property is not available in the exchange version you have referenced.

> The property was introduced in Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1
>   (SP1).

See reference in the Remarks section of this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709517(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_2)

You would need to install that [service pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=21570) and change your code to the below:

```
thisConnection = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I guessed it might be that, but had failed to find the article joining up the Exchange version with that property.